# Projection homomorphism of an abelian group is closed

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a an abelian topological group and let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup. Is the projection homomorphism $\pi:G\to G/\Gamma$ closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, taking $G=\mathbb{R}$ and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}$, the set $\{n+1/2^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ but is image in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question here, what if $G=\mathbb R^n$. Is $\pi(\mathbb R^m)$ closed for any $m<n$?

Comment: No.  For instance, if $G=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}^2$, then a line through the origin of irrational slope (which can be identified with $\mathbb{R}$ after a change of basis) has dense image in the quotient.

Comment: Thanks! Is the answer still the same for $\pi(V)$ where $V=\{x\in \mathbb R^n;\ x_1=0,\dots, x_m=0\}$?

Comment: How is that different from your previous question?

Comment: Sorry, maybe this is a special thing in the analytic case. I mean, if $\pi:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^n/\Gamma$ is holomorphic,  then $\pi(V)$ is closed. I don't understand this!

Comment: That's still not true, by essentially the same counterexample.